# Facebook app compromised/hacked

Tags: facebook

I haven't used my facebook app for a while, and when I tried to access it today, it didn't want to load. When I disabled secure browsing, Chrome gave me the following warning when I loaded the app from the canvas url:

"apps.facebook.com contains content from methuenedge.com, a site known to distribute malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site."

How can I solve this issue? Could my app secret have been compromised? If so, and if I need to reset my app secret, will current users of my app still have access to it or do they need to re-install?

Thank You

Comment: You'll need to contact whoever (Google?) supplies the blacklist for Chrome and see why your site is listed

Answer (score 1):

If you can still access the developer app and see that you are the only developer of the app then it is unlikely that your Facebook app configuration has been hacked. What may have happened is that the web site which hosts your app may have been hacked and bad things put in your HTML code. Do you get the same warning when you go to the direct URL for you app? E.g. www.myhostingprovider/myaccount/appname/index.php etc rather than apps.facebook.com/appname)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes when I enter the direct app url as you said above, I still get the warning. I also uploaded some of my older php files (that in my view cannot have any malicious code)but id does not solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe it is your app code which is compromised in this case. Take a look at your app source and make sure that there is no additional code added by a malicious party. Also, Does chrome give you an option to ask why your page is listed as "hacked"? Usually there is a link for the site owner in the error message.

Comment: Any luck? Was that the answer?